# NameError in Admin::Users#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

When i want to delete a user with ActiveAdmin, i got the error below :

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_18841639d7" on table "recherches" DETAIL: Key (id)=(5) is still referenced from table "recherches". : DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1
```

I fixed this by adding `has_many :recherches, dependent: :destroy` but now i get the following error :

```
NameError in Admin::Users#index


Showing /home/charles/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #2 raised:

uninitialized constant User::Recherch
```

Both errors are related to the class Recherche but i can't find where the problem comes from. Is is the controller? The model? Anything else?

Comment: Can you update your both model code here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from your information, because of this code:

```
has_many :recherches, dependent: :destroy
```

...Rails is trying to turn the plural 'recherches' into a singular 'recherch', which is not the name of your class - 'Recherche', as you called it. In this case, you have to override Rails' naming conventions:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'recherche', 'recherches'
end
```